# How can I modify a script to delete the row in base of the first and second column?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

As it is the script only looks at the given value on the second column, however, I would like to add another requirement where it looks at the first column as well.

```
function deleteRowsToday() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Staffing Data 0');
  var t = ss.getSheetByName('Data Collector');
  var r = s.getRange(1,2,s.getLastRow());
  var v = r.getValues();
  var x = t.getRange(2,2).getValue();
  for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    if(v[0,i]== x)
      s.deleteRow(i+1);
```

I would like to add the value y as well which is another criteria I'm giving in base to delete that row. And it should be deleting the row only if both `x` & `y` are present.

I tried modifying the script, but it still deletes the row only if `x` or `y` are present.

```
function deleteRowsToday() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Staffing Data 0');
  var t = ss.getSheetByName('Data Collector');
  var r = s.getRange(1,2,s.getLastRow());
  var v = r.getValues();
  var x = t.getRange(2,2).getValue();
  var y = t.getRange(2,1).getValue(); 
  for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    if(v[0,i]== x && y)
      s.deleteRow(i+1);
```

In the Sheet this is the "Data Collector" tab
[image]

X should be taking value B2 and y value A2

Then in the tab "Staffing Data 0" it should find the value x on the second column and y on the first column, and if both match the script should delte the row.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- Replace `if(v[0,i]== x && y)` with `if(v[i][0] == y && v[i][1] == x)`
- Replace `s.getRange(1,2,s.getLastRow())` with `s.getRange(1,1,s.getLastRow(),s.getLastColumn()).getValues();`

---

### Solution:

```
 function deleteRowsToday() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const s = ss.getSheetByName('Staffing Data 0');
  const t = ss.getSheetByName('Data Collector');
  const v = s.getRange(1,1,s.getLastRow(),s.getLastColumn()).getValues(); // <- new code
  const x = t.getRange(2,2).getValue();
  const y = t.getRange(2,1).getValue(); 
   
      for(let i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    if(v[i][0] == y && v[i][1] == x) // <- new code
      s.deleteRow(i+1);
    }    
 }
```

Comment: Hello Marios, Thanks for the quick answer. I tried adding the script to the file however is still not deleting the rows.  I don't know if I mentioned, the value x can be found on the 2nd column of 'Staffing Data 0' and y can be found on the first column. I don't know if this makes any difference.

Comment: @RobertKiss thanks for your feedback. In your code, `x` and `y` come from the sheet `Data Collector` and this is why I did exactly the same. Otherwise send screenshots of the two tabs explaining what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: I just added some screenshots form the sheets as well. Hope this makes it clear, thanks for your help

Comment: @RobertKiss can you change the format of `A2` value to match the first column of the main file. For example in `A2` you have `44112` and in the first column you have `44,112.00` and run the script again ?

Comment: I just tried doing that and it still does not deletes it.

Comment: Copied the exact same value from the Data collector to the Staffing Data 0 tab. It's only running the script and not deleting the row which has 44112 and pl_PL

Comment: Tried as well giving both first 2 columns in the Staffing Data 0 tab the same name (in this case pt_PT) and as well x & y have both the value pt_PT. And this way it deleted the row. So it looks like the script only deletes if both are the same.

Comment: @RobertKiss **I updated my answer**. Please try and execute my new solution. However, if this also does not work, then the only way to resolve this is for you to share part of your sheet. This does not have to be the full data. Just a small sample to reproduce the issue and solve it. Of course remove all your sensitive information.